# Concatenate multiple files and create new file based on the value

Tags: awk

I have more than 50 files as like this

dell.txt

```
Name  Id  Year  Value
xx.01 45  1990  2k
SS.01 89  2000  6.0k
```

Hp.txt

```
Name  Id  Year  Value
xx.01 48  1994  21k
SS.01 80  2001  2k
```

Apple.txt

```
Name  Id  Year  Value
xx.02 45  1990  20k
SS.01 89  2000  60k
kp.03 23  1996  530k
```

I just need to make a new file as like this

```
Name  Id  Year  dell  Hp  Apple 
xx.01 45  1990  2k    0   0
xx.01 48  1994  0     21k 0
xx.02 45  1990  0     0   20k
SS.01 80  2001  0     2k  0
SS.01 89  2000  6.0k  0   60k
kp.03 23  1996  0     0   530k
```

I tried with paste for concatenation but it is adding different order. any other way using awk? I used flowing code:

```
$ awk ' FNR==1{ if (!($0 in h)){file=h[$0]=i++} else{file=h[$0];next} } {print >> (file)} ' *.txt –
```

Comment: Can you share your attempt?

Comment: I used flowing code awk '
  FNR==1{
    if (!($0 in h)){file=h[$0]=i++}
    else{file=h[$0];next}
  }
  {print >> (file)}
' *.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with GNU `awk` and is giving output in sorted format.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  tfile=FILENAME
  sub(/\..*/,"",tfile)
  file=(file?file OFS:"")tfile
  header=($1 FS $2 FS $3)
  next
}
{
  a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 "@" FILENAME]=$NF
}
END{
  print header,file
  for(i in a){
    oldi=i
    split(i,arr,"@")
    sub(/@.*/,"",i)
    printf("%s ",i)
    for(i=1;i<=ARGIND;i++){
      val=(val?val OFS:"")((arr[1] "@" ARGV[i]) in a?a[oldi]:0)
    }
    printf("%s\n",val)
    val=""
  }
}
' dell.txt Hp.txt Apple.txt  | sort -k1 | column -t
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                               ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==1{                                                             ##Checking if this is 1st line.
  tfile=FILENAME
  sub(/\..*/,"",tfile)
  file=(file?file OFS:"")tfile                                   ##Creating file which has all Input_file names in it.
  header=($1 FS $2 FS $3)                                           ##Header has 3 fields in it from 1st line.
  next                                                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 "@" FILENAME]=$NF                                ##Creating a with index of 1st, 2nd, 3rd fields @ Input_file name and has value as last field.
}
END{                                                                ##Starting END block of this awk program from here.
  print header,file                                                 ##Printing header and file variables here.
  for(i in a){                                                      ##Traversing through a here.
    oldi=i                                                          ##Setting i value as oldi here.
    split(i,arr,"@")                                                ##Splitting i with arr delimiter as @ here.
    sub(/@.*/,"",i)                                                 ##Substituting from @ to till last of line with NULL.
    printf("%s ",i)                                                 ##Printing i here.
    for(i=1;i<=ARGIND;i++){                                         ##Running a for loop till ARGIND value from i=1
      val=(val?val OFS:"")((arr[1] "@" ARGV[i]) in a?a[oldi]:0)     ##Creating val if arr[1] "@" ARGV[i] in a then have a value with index a[oldi] or put 0.
    }
    printf("%s\n",val)                                              ##Printing val here with new line.
    val=""                                                          ##Nullifying val here.
  }
}
' dell.txt Hp.txt Apple.txt  | sort -k1 | column -t                 ##Mentioning Input_file names, sorting output and then using column -t to look output well.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Name   Id  Year  dell  Hp   Apple
SS.01  80  2001  0     2k   0
SS.01  89  2000  6.0k  0    6.0k
SS.01  89  2000  60k   0    60k
kp.03  23  1996  0     0    530k
xx.01  45  1990  2k    0    0
xx.01  48  1994  0     21k  0
xx.02  45  1990  0     0    20k
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk script to join the files as required.

```sh
BEGIN { OFS = "\t"}

NR==1 { col[++c] = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 }

FNR==1 {
    split(FILENAME, arr, ".")
    f = arr[1]
    col[++c] = f
    next
}

{
    id[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3] = $4
    cell[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS f] = $4
}
    
END {
    for (i=1; i<=length(col); i++) {
        printf col[i] OFS
    }
    printf ORS
    
    for (i in id) {
        printf i OFS
        for (c=2; c<=length(col); c++) {
            printf (cell[i OFS col[c]] ? cell[i OFS col[c]] : "0") OFS
        }
        printf ORS
    }
}
```

Usage:

```sh
awk -f tst.awk *.txt  | sort -nk3
```

Note that the glob fetches the files in alphabetical order and the arguments order determines the column order of the output. If you want a different column order, you have to order the arguments, for example like below.

Output is a real tab-columned file, but if you want a tab-like look with spaces, pipe to `column -t`

---

### Testing

Using your sample files and providing their order:

```
> awk -f tst.awk dell.txt Hp.txt Apple.txt  | sort -nk3 | column -t
Name   Id  Year  dell  Hp   Apple
xx.01  45  1990  2k    0    0
xx.02  45  1990  0     0    20k
xx.01  48  1994  0     21k  0
kp.03  23  1996  0     0    530k
SS.01  89  2000  6.0k  0    60k
SS.01  80  2001  0     2k   0
```